# Cannot clone private repo from Vagrant provision file

Tags: git, ssh, vagrant, ssh-keys

I have vagrant provision script containing shell commands. When I try to clone private repo via git and private\public keys within this script I get an error:

```
Cloning into 'brand.api'...

Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

But when I exclude `git clone ...` command from provision script and call it myself within vagrant box everything is ok.

Here is the provision file:

```
#setting up Git
apt-get install -y git
mkdir ~/.ssh
mkdir ~/bin
cp /vagrant/bin/git-ssh.sh  ~/bin
cp /vagrant/keys/mygit.key ~/.ssh/mygit.key 
cp /vagrant/keys/mygit.pub ~/.ssh/mygit.pub

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
echo 'export GIT_SSH=~/bin/git-ssh.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

#installing brand-api
git clone git@****.ru:brand.api.git
```

What's the problem?

**UPDATED**

After adding git repo host to known_hosts I get this:

```
Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

But if I login to my box via `vagrant ssh` and try to clone everything is OK.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The SSH key of the git server is not known/trusted. When you clone the repo manually on the VM, you get a prompt asking to verify the fingerprint, right?

You can either skip the host key verification in `~/.ssh/config` (or globally in `/etc/ssh/config` or alike):

```
Host git.example.com
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Or you can add the key in advance to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` (or `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`). For example:

```
ssh-keyscan -H git.example.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: It was not immediately apparent to me that I had to do this (ssh-keyscan) on the vagrant box. In hindsight it's obvious. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: For some reason ssh-keyscan command kept throwing "no hostkey alg".  To get it working I had to add the -t flag.

"ssh-keyscan -t rsa -H git.example.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts"

Answer (score 1):

This works to me..

Try put this in your *provision.sh*:

```
sudo -u vagrant git clone git@****.ru:brand.api.git
```

Instead of:

```
git clone git@****.ru:brand.api.git
```